# Python is creating Data files rather than ASCII while using file handler with a+

Tags: python

I am dumping all the output of pexpect module in a file. I am using below code to that

```
def __init__(self, telnet_switch_ip, telnet_port):
    stringtosend = "telnet " + telnet_switch_ip + " " + telnet_port
    fileName = telnet_switch_ip + "_" + telnet_port + "_" + "_station."
    self.child = pexpect.spawn(stringtosend,maxread=8000)
    path1 = os.path.join(self.files[0], fileName)
    mylog = open(path1, 'a+')
    self.child.logfile = mylog
```

It is creating files likes this in ubuntu

```
172.31.240.31_2009__station.: ASCII text, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators
172.31.240.31_2010__station.: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

This is expected

```
172.31.240.31_2009__station.: data
172.31.240.31_2010__station.: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

Why I am getting sometimes `data` file. problem is that I am not able to open such files in mozilla firefox. Any idea why sometimes I am getting `data` file

Comment: I'd not worry too much about what the data type of the file is shown. Look at the *contents* of the file (in say, a text editor) and see what's showing up that you didn't expect (if anything).

Comment: Text editor is displaying the file but firefox is giving error saying cannot open BIN file

Comment: You might want to give your file a proper file extension then. Firefox has to guess what format the file is in, and it seems to be guessing wrongly. Depending on how you're loading it (is it via a web server, or just with a `file:/...` url?), there may be extra levels of confusion.

Comment: This problem is not for the Firefox I assume. You can check the file types I have shared above. These are the output of `file *` in Linux. One file is displayed as `data` and other as `ASCII text`

Comment: Yes, but `file` can only guess at the contents of a file. It says "data" when it has no idea (perhaps because the file is very short). I suggest naming the files with a `.txt` extension, instead of the very unusual bare dot you're using. That will hint to programs like Firefox (or your web server) that the files are text, even if they can't otherwise tell for sure.